# How to get the total time from out time minus start time in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I have a problem here. I want to get the total hour from the last time (DateTime.Now) minus txtin.Text which is already selected from the datagridview and stored into the text box.

**This is what I've done in c# visual studio 2010**

```
public outForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    LoadData();
    ResetAllTextFields();
    TOTAL.Text = ((DateTime.Now) - (txtin.Text)) * 3;
}
```

but, the problem is the syntax is error.. it said that 
"Operator - cannot be applied to operand of the system.datetime and string"

Which is
 1. system.datetime => (DateTime.Now)
 2. string => (txtin.Text)

nb. 3 is price per hours.. So, what should i do to get the total hours??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to parse `txtin.Text` to a `DateTime` (e.g. with `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`) first. Then the subtraction will work to give you a `TimeSpan`, which you can work with.

Comment: i will try it first.. i will back soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the textbox date to a `DateTime` variable, and then subtract the hours from `Now`:

```
 int hoursDiff = DateTime.Now.Hour - Covnert.ToDateTime(txtin.Text).Hour;
 hoursDiff = hoursDiff * 3;
 TOTAL.Text = hoursDiff.ToString();
```

Comment: nah it's correct.. thanks for your advice.. but, i must put them on the cell click in the data grid view not in the InitializeComponent.. anyway, thanks once more